# Savoir vs Connaitre for "to know a word"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Although I'm familiar with the differences between *connaître* and *savoir*, I am unsure which one best expresses the idea behind "I don't know that word," in response to someone using French vocabulary which I am unfamiliar with.

I am guessing it is *connaître* that I want.....*Agape? Je ne connais pas ce mot. Ça veut dire quoi ?*

Comment: In general I feel like *savoir + nom* is most natural if there's ellipsis involved or if the noun could be taken to refer to a clause (e.g. « Je le sais » → « Je sais que ... »). Other times *connaître + nom* works best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ***Je ne sais pas ce mot***

might have been used several centuries ago to state you don't know the word meaning. It might still be used in some contexts, for example a student has to learn a list of words and one of them is not known by him/her.

> ***Je ne connais pas ce mot***

usually means you never heard about it.

You might know a word without knowing what it means though:

> ***Je connais le mot agape, mais ne sais pas ce qu'il veut dire***

I would then translate:

> ***I don't know that word***

with either (existence)

> ***Je ne connais pas ce mot***

or (meaning)

> ***Je ne sais pas ce que ce mot veut dire***.